# How do I perform an std::move of an xvalue into a void* ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, freertos

I've written a wrapper for FreeRTOS's queue datatype. Which is a C datatype. Now for primitives and 'simple' datatypes the implementation works perfectly. However, I cannot find a generic way to transfer ownership to the FreeRTOS queue using, for example, a std::unique_ptr.

Yes, using ptr.release() would solve the issue, but it would make the RTOSQueue class a whole lot less generic. What if I'm passing a struct that has a std::unique_ptr as member variable? I shouldn't write a specialization for every possible struct.

```cpp
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <queue.h>

template <class T>
class RTOSQueue {
    QueueHandle_t queueHandle;
    TickType_t timeout;

public:
    RTOSQueue(size_t len, TickType_t timeout) : timeout(timeout) {
        queueHandle = xQueueCreate(len, sizeof(T));
    }

    void enqueue(const T& v) {
        xQueueSendToBack(queueHandle, static_cast<const void*>(&std::move(v)), timeout);
    }

    T dequeue() {
        uint8_t rxBuffer[sizeof(T)];
        T rxValue;

        xQueueReceive(queueHandle, rxBuffer, timeout);
        std::memcpy(&rxValue, rxBuffer, sizeof(T));

        return std::move(rxValue);
    }
};

struct S {
  std::unique_ptr ptr = std::make_unique(1234);
}

int main() {
  RTOSQueue q;
  S s;

  q.enqueue(s);
}
```

The current implementation gives

```
../include/RTOSCircularBuffer.hpp:18:64: error: taking address of xvalue (rvalue reference)
         xQueueSendToBack(queueHandle, static_cast<const void*>(&std::move(v)), timeout);
```

which shows the current code is invalid C++. The essential target is to prevent the v inside enqueue from being destructed, but I cannot find a tidy way, i.e. without unnecessary copying, to perform this.

Comment: You can not pass any fancy objects through that queue. Only POD types without any pointers. Just like with any other binary storage. "to prevent the v inside enqueue to be prevented from destruction" - this part does not make sense.

Comment: `dequeue` suggests that the object is transferred as an contiguous array of bytes, but `enqueue` doesn't even know how long the object is? And besides, just take `std::vector<int>`. Dequeuing `sizeof(vector<int>)` won't work at all. You need the integers in the vector, not 3 pointers into the original memory space. This idea is irrevocably flawed.

Comment: @MSalters the idea is not irrevocably flawed. The design of FreeRTOS's queue is that the size of one queue is defined during initialization (xQueueCreate).

Comment: @VTT it may be a weird statement, but the destruction of type T invokes undefined behavior to elements that the struct inside the queue reference. std::move normally prevents 'ordinary' destruction, in the sense that any unique_ptr does shouldn't delete any allocated memory, in my specific case. Which is exactly what my code should perform in order for this queue to work. Unfortunately I don't know a trivial way to get this done, without a place to move to.

Comment: Edited the last paragraph

Comment: I'm not sure where are you getting these weird ideas from, but invoking `std::move` does literally nothing on its own. And it is not possible to change object lifetime or transfer object ownership to and then from queued bytes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I looked into the semantics of move, it doesn't do anything except to cast to a && value (I did learn something, which is a good thing). In this case it doesn't do anything. Is there a way a to make queue wrapper like this compatible with move semantics? I'm assuming it can't be since you suggested that earlier.